# Coq define a type constructor for injective functions

Tags: coq

An injective function from type `A` to `B` maps distinct inputs to distinct outputs, but might not cover the entire range.

e.g.

```
f : ℕ -> ℕ
f = λx. 2*x
```

I'm trying to figure out how to express such a thing in Coq.

I think the Coq way of talking about such an object would be some kind of product type where one element is the is the "raw" function `A -> B` itself and another is a proof that said function is injective.

I don't know how to express this in the syntax of Coq though ... more specifically how to be able to refer to the name of the function in the definition of a type in the same "structure" and what kind of product-like thing is most appropriate.

I've tried putting a number of things in the ellpises here, but am not able to capture the function.

```
Definition injection (A : Prop) (B: Prop) :=
  A -> B /\ ...
```

I'm stuck on what to put in the ellipses.

Another example definition that doesn't capture the right thing is something like this:

```
Definition injection (A : Prop) (B: Prop) :=
  A * (not (A = A)) -> B * (not (B = B)).
```

The problem here is that `=` is operating on the types themselves ... and, even if this definition could be massaged into a better one, it would require an obnoxious amount of plumbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define a property called `injective` and add it as a condition to the lemmas requiring their functions to be injective:

```
Definition injective {A B} (f : A -> B) := forall x1 x2, f x1 = f x2 -> x1 = x2.

Lemma inj_comp {A B C} (f : B -> C) (g : A -> B) :
  injective f -> injective g -> injective (fun x => f (g x)).
```

This is the approach taken in Mathcomp/SSReflect (see the [definition](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/4d1de421c2df95503e4643f41903d214e0c2fb19/plugins/ssr/ssrfun.v#L617) and a usage e.g. [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/4d1de421c2df95503e4643f41903d214e0c2fb19/plugins/ssr/ssrfun.v#L664)).

Bundling a function and a proof of its injectivity might not be the best way to go, unless you are developing a theory of injective functions.

Comment: What does it mean if you leave off a `: type` in `forall x1 x2 , ...`.

Comment: It means Coq has to figure out the types on it's own. And indeed it can do it in this case: e.g. for `f x1` to be well-typed, `x1` must be of type `A`, since we have given the type of `f`.

Comment: does coq fix/infer the types out at definition time or usage time?

Comment: At definition time

Comment: Gregory, note that since `A`, `B`, and `C` are parameters, this applies to all values of `A`, `B` and `C`, so you can use this lemma for any function `f` that you have.